# List-group-horizontal dentro de un list-group [Bootstrap]

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap-4

Estoy intentando generar un "list-group-horizontal" dentro de un "list-group", pero se visualiza como si fuera un unico list. He intentado varias formas pero no consigo terminar de sacarlo.

Este es mi ultimo intento:

```
 <ul class="list-group">
     <li class="list-group-item ">
       <div>
         <ul class="list-group-horizontal">
              <li class="list-group-item">Elemento 1 </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Elemento 2 </li>
         </ul>
       </div>
     </li>
     <li class="list-group-item">
         <div>
         <ul class="list-group-horizontal">
              <li class="list-group-item">Elemento 1 </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Elemento 2 </li>
         </ul>
       </div>
     </li>
</ul>
```

¿Es posible conseguir algo asi o existe algun componente especifico para lo que intento?

Comment: te falta añadir la clase `.list-group` en las listas horizontales. Debería ser así: `<ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal">`

Comment: Ya lo he intentado, me lo muestra como un unico list-group vertical :\

Comment: A mi me funciona añadiendo eso: https://jsfiddle.net/blonfu/9z83ta5s/

Comment: Ya he localizado el error. Tu respuesta era correcta, el problema residia en que el proyecto no usa la ultima version de Bootstrap y los "list-group-horizontal" todavia no se habian añadido. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema resuelto, la versión de Bootstrap del proyecto no soporta la clase "list-group-horizontal", el proyecto actualmente usa la versión 4.0 de Bootstrap.

Leyendo la documentación, el componente "List-group-horizontal" no se añade hasta la versión 4.3.

Comment: Desenvuelve un poco más tu respuesta, ¿Qué versión de Bootstrap está usando el proyecto? ¿Para qué versión está soportada la clase 'list-group-horizontal'?¿La clase 'list-group-horizontal' corresponde a un archivo modificado de CSS que haya usado?. Saludos

Comment: El proyecto actualmente usa la version 4.0 de Bootstrap. Leyendo la documentación, el componente "List-group-horizontal" no se añade hasta la version 4.3.